# Using 'and' with Kohana Jelly

Tags: php, kohana, jelly

I am counting how many rows there are in a database that match *two* conditions

```
$rows = Jelly::select('brief')->where('creator_id', '=', $this->view->user->id, 'and', 'name', '=', $name)->count();
```

I have done this before a long time ago and have forgotten how. I was wondering if this is the correct way of doing it.

I just can't seem to find my answer through Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$rows = Jelly::select('brief')->where('creator_id', '=', $this->view->user->id )->where('name', '=', $name)->count();
```